# Удаление элемента двусвязного списка C++

Tags: c++, двусвязный-список

При успешном удалении должно возвращать true, но почему то всегда возвращает фолс.
Вот класс:

```
struct Num
{
    int number;
    bool ring;
    Num *next, *prev;
};

class List
{
protected :
    Num *head, *tail;

public :
     List():head(NULL),tail(NULL){}
    ~List();
    int genNum();
    void Add(int x);
    bool Remove(int i);
};
```

И моя попытка переделать удаление :

```
bool List::Remove(int idx)
{
Num *current = head;
Num *temp = nullptr;
int i = 0;

while(current->next != NULL)
{
    if(i != idx)
    {
        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }

    else
    {
        temp = current->prev;
        current->prev = current->next;
        current->next->prev = temp;

        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: ну так в else oн никогда и не заходит

Comment: @TigerTV.ru ааааа, какая глупая ошибка... Спасибо

Comment: и если даже исправите это, то  утечка памяти и  логическая ошибка гарантировано

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а как исправить?

Comment: @DigitalResistance Удалить объект из памяти который удаляете из списка?

Comment: Ваш класс должен иметь указатели на голову и хвост списка.  Вы  же обьявляете указатель  Num *current = new Num;  который указывает на новый  узель. И  на что указывет   current->prev?...  Короче без данных и конструктора вашего класса, я не смогу ответить на ваш вопрос. Покажите класс List

Comment: @ARHovsepyan исправил, посмотрите сверху :)

Comment: И я исправил немного. Теперь сойдет

Comment: @ARHovsepyan спасибо Вам огромное :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, но впредь не исправляйте  вопрос после ответов, а  напишите снизу правильную версию как дополнение, чтобы комментарии и ответы не висели в воздухе, и любой читающий понел бы их смысль, хотя я невнимательно смотрел, и у вас есть еще ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я только исправлю часть кода, что посчитал неправильным.

```
else
{
    if (idx == 1) {
       temp = head;
       head = current;
    }
    else {
       temp = current->prev; // указывает на узель, который должен удаляться
       current->prev = temp->prev;
       current->prev->next = current;
    }
    delete temp;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: хотя по хорошему  idx должен иметь беззнаковый тип и не иметь нулевое значение ,  эти условия тоже должны учитываться. И в самом  начале функции нужно проверять  if (idx < 1)   return false;